# Why am I unable to install pylbfgs package in Anaconda?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I am unable to install pylbfgs by using the conda prompt. I tried with the following command line:

```
> conda install -c fgregg pylbfgs
```

Then the result is:

> Solving environment: failed
>
> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>
> - opencv
> - pylbfgs
>
> Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

And I used:

```
> pip install pylbfgs
```

Then the result is:

> Requirement already satisfied: pylbfgs in c:\users\kk\anaconda3\lib\
>   site-packages (0.2.0.11)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.1 in c:\users\kk\anaconda
>   3\lib\site-packages (from pylbfgs) (1.14.3)

`pip install pylbfgs` worked for me.

But when I run the code in Spyder then the result is:

> File "C:/Users/kk/Desktop/python/Task6.py", line 59, in 
>        from pyLBFGS import owlqn
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLBFGS'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work for me' are you getting an error, what behaviour are you experiencing, what do you expect?

Comment: I expected to install pylbfgs. You can open the link attached here and see what exactly happens to me    https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiAkw.jpg

Comment: Please don't post images of your exception, just [edit] your post and include the actual exception.

Comment: Hey AChampion I edited the post and updated my results

Answer (score 1):

Please try `import lbfgs`. The `top_level.txt` file of the package, which seems to indicate what name should be used for the import, contains `lbfgs` and not `pylbfgs`